# Curves Knotted in the Torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I've been struggling with the following problem. I suspect it's actually not so hard, but I'm missing something relatively obvious about the proof. The attached image will help.

Suppose $K$ and $L$ are two curves inside the solid torus $\mathbb S^1 \times D$, which are each on one side of the hole, and intersect each other like chain links at each end of the loop. Can we show that K is not null-homotopic in $(\mathbb S^1 \times D) - L$?

It is really clear to me that if we are thinking of these curves as existing in just $\mathbb R^3$ that we can unlink the two by passing one curve around the other - but that we can't do this in the torus because the central hole stops you from deforming the curves to be close together. I suspect something like this is key, but I don't know how to write down the proof. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Here is a description of the knots. The torus is solid - the curves are not on the surface]

Comment: The link you are describing (if I am interpreting you correctly) is called the Bing double of the unknot. It is probably easier to show that a lift of $K$ is not null-homotopic in the universal cover of $S^1\times D=\Bbb R \times D$ with each lift of $L$ removed (which is clearly a cover of your space), and use the fact that covers are injective on $\pi_1$.

Comment: Also I'm still trying to attach the picture... trying to figure out how.

Comment: I guess I interpreted you correctly. You should try my suggestion.

Comment: @PVAL So wait, we lift to the universal cover, which is a solid cylinder. Then $L$ should be a loop in this cylinder. Somehow I want to say that $K$ still goes around $L$ in a non-trivial way.

Comment: Lift to the universal cover of the solid torus which is a solid cyllinder and remove all lifts of $L$. The result is a solid cyllinder with infinitely many unknots (which are all unlinked) removed. One can compute $\pi_1$ of this space by Van-Kampen's (by thinking of this space as a union of infinitely many cyllinders  with a single unknot removed)to get $\pi_1$ is freely generated by the meridians of all of the removed unknots. Now write a lift of $K$ as a product of these meridians. Note a solid cyllinder with an unknot removed is homeomorphic to a solid torus.